# Hosted WPF Control to move a path programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

What I have is a WINFORM with an element host that hosts a WPF user control.
On the wpf user control I have a Path.
What i want to do is move the path on the user control, according to strings that I read from a file.
Meaning, I have a loop that reads a line from the file and according to that line, "moves" the path.

My problem is that the path isn't moving on the screen. All I have is the initial path and the last position.

### The code on the winform:

```
private void WinForm_Method()
{
     // This method invokes the method on the wpf user control

     Type t = ElemHost.Child.GetType();  
     t.InvokeMember("MovePath", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, ElemHost.Child, null);
}
```

### The code on the wpf user control:

```
public void MovePath()
{  
 string line = null;

 //Read data from file.
 // Every line is of the format "M x1,y1 x2,y2 x3,y3 x4,y4 x1,y1"
 using (StreamReader SR = new StreamReader("DataFile"))  
 {
   while ((line = SR.ReadLine()) != null)     
   {
     MyPath.Data = Geometry.Parse(line);
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: The while loop blocks the UI thread until the loop is finished. Hence you only see the result of the last line in the file. In order to make this work, you should read lines in a time-controlled manner and let the UI update itself from time to time. You might use a DispatcherTimer and read the file line by line in its Tick event handler. By setting the timer interval you could control the speed of your animation.

Comment: It's common issue. You do job at once without giving a chance for your form to redraw anything. Solution is easy: split job into peaces (using `Timer`) or do it in parallel (`BackgroundWorker`, `Task`, `Thread`).

Comment: Thank you guys, it works perfectly. I used a windows.forms.timer for scheduling the call for the invoked method.